# WPF : Assigning to RichTextBox.Document extremely slow (7 minutes!)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, richtextbox

I'm constructing a formatted `FlowDocument` from XML. The XML is well formed and consists mainly of 10,000 nodes each with a single node with a 6 character string value.

Parsing the XML to an `XElement` and constructing the `FlowDocument` in memory takes about 5 seconds. Assigning the `FlowDocument` to the `Document` property of a `RichTextBox` in my application then takes about 7 minutes, and maxes out the CPU for that time.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
// The following six lines of code execute in about 5 seconds

var xml = XElement.Parse(response.Data);

PrettyXmlConverter px = new PrettyXmlConverter();
FlowDocument fd = px.Render(xml);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(new Run(response.TimeStamp.ToShortDateString() + " " + response.TimeStamp.ToLongTimeString()));
fd.Blocks.InsertBefore(fd.Blocks.ElementAt(0), p);

// This line of code takes about 7 minutes and maxes out the CPU for that time.
tbResponse.Document = fd;
```

I'm wondering what's going on here. I've profiled the code and see scores of thousands of calls to unmanaged methods such as `fsFormatSubtrackBottomless` and `SubtrackFormatParaBottomless`.

Can anyone shed any light on the problem, or come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't find a solution to this.

I'm using a workaround - I simply don't "pretty print" messages over a certain size.

If anyone has a better solution, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 4):

Following excerpt from MacDonald's [Pro WPF in C# 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058) book, p. 966:

*The WPF RichTextBox, like most of the rich text controls that have preceded it, can be a bit sluggish. If you need to hold huge amounts of data, use intricate logic to handle key presses, or add effects such as automatic formatting (for example, Visual Studio’s syntax highlighting or Word’s spelling-checker underlining), **the WPF RichTextBox probably won’t provide the performance you need**.*

Comment: @leetNightshade: Well, this is what comes up as a paid ad when you google for it: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/dotnet-rich-text-editor-control/?gclid=CP668O7M2rgCFUVb3godDRkAAg  I also know there are open source ones available, both at codeplex and code project, just can't remember their names.

Comment: Hm, nice find! I did manage to find an alternative, though for a different use than the one you shared (I haven't tried it out yet): https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox

Comment: +1 Very much different than anything else I have seen.  Thanks for sharing.